# how to call php function with parameters in href html tag

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I want to call sendEmail($email) function with it's parameters in the **href tag** when I click on the link I get a page wrote in it FORBIDDEN "you don't have permission to access the root folder on this server"

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
function sendEmail($email) {
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();         
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'zebalaGP@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '******';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';   
$mail->Port = 587;            
$mail->From = 'zebalaGP@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'ana grin emoticon';
$mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);          
$mail->Subject = 'blabla !';
$mail->Body = 'Salam,, <br> <b> thanks for your participation grin emoticon you are especial for us grin emoticon  ';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
if (!$mail->send()) {
echo 'no';
    return false;
} else {
echo 'sent grin emoticon';
    return true;
}
}


$email='ayaradwan_93@yahoo.com';
//sendEmail($email); 
$r=' <a href= ".<?php sendEmail($email); ?>." > Send Email </a> ';
echo $r;
?>
```

Comment: you cant do it like that. HTML is front end and PHP is backend. You will need JS/ AJAX

Comment: actually I don't know how can I use AJEX !, would you tell me how can I use it with example :)) thank u

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: [Basics of jQuery AJAX](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing server-side code and client-side code.  They run *at completely different times* in *completely different contexts* on (usually) *completely different computers*.

It's not clear exactly what your code is going to do, but it's likely that you are executing the `sendEmail()` function *immediately* when the page is requested.  Then since you're not echoing any result, the `a` tag looks like this:

```
<a href="">Send Email</a>
```

Two things:

1. The email has already been sent.
2. An empty `href` will try to load the current page or some default directory listing or something.  It definitely *won't* invoke server-side code.

What you're trying to do is a little more involved than you think.  The simplest approach, given what you have so far, would be to move all of the email functionality to another page.  Something like `sendMail.php`.  Then the page you have here would simply link to that other one:

```
<a href="sendMail.php">Send Email</a>
```

When the user clicks that link, they'd invoke the second page which itself would call `sendEmail()` internally and then display a result to the user.  Something like:

```
<?php

    // define sendEmail here like you already do

    sendEmail();

?>
<p>The email has been sent.  Thank you!</p>
```

So the *request* to send the email comes from one page, the *action* of actually sending it is on another.

You can make this increasingly feature-rich in various ways:

1. Instead of a link, use a form which posts values to `sendEmail.php` so it can use those values when composing the email.
2. Instead of linking to the page, have a button with some JavaScript code which creates an AJAX request to `sendEmail.php` to send the mail without leaving the current page.
3. etc.

But the basic idea is that your server-side code and client-side code can't interact directly.  They are separated by HTTP requests.  If the client-side code wants to invoke some server-side functionality, it needs to make an HTTP request to a server-side resource (a "page" in this case) which performs that action.

Comment: okay ! but I want to send the email in the parameter, so the email would be send !

Comment: @AyaRadwan: In your current code you hard-code that parameter.  You can still do that.  Or do you mean that you want the *user* to supply their email address?  If that's the case then you'd want to use a form instead of a link.  Take a look at some PHP tutorials, but basically your form would include an `input type="text"` where the user can enter an email address.

Comment: the emails are reteived from the database and i want to when I click on it sending email

Comment: @AyaRadwan: There's no indication of that in your code, so I can't be particularly specific.  But in the design I propose what you could do is fetch the emails from the database on the first page and include them as query string parameters in the links, something like: `<a href="sendEmail.php?address=<?php echo urlencode($someEmailAddress); ?>">Send Email</a>`  Then in the second page you can get the address from `$_GET['address']`.  *Be careful* not to expose a web page which blindly sends emails to anybody who requests it.  Spammers/bots *love* to abuse pages like that.

Comment: I can't run it ,,
I have the testEmail file where I write the function sendEmail($email) ..
and other php class where I put the href tag this tag is not read i wrote it in php variable so the php tag <?php echo urlencode($someEmailAddress); ?> read it as string

Comment: @AyaRadwan: Perhaps you can elaborate more in the question?  Or if it's a new enough problem, perhaps a new question?  Long comment threads are not well suited to diagnose code problems, and it's not clear what you're describing.

Comment: thank you I pass the data in the parameter like this $email=$object['email'];
$r='<a href="testEmail.php?address='.$email.'">Send Email</a>'; ..... appreciate your effort ^_^  @David

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is a `<a>` link to a php page with some `GET` parameters. Then, in your php page, if the GET parameters are set, you use them to send email.

It could be something like this, if you want it to be the same page.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
function sendEmail($email) {
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->isSMTP();         
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Username = 'zebalaGP@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
  $mail->Password = '******';                           // SMTP password
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';   
  $mail->Port = 587;            
  $mail->From = 'zebalaGP@gmail.com';
  $mail->FromName = 'ana grin emoticon';
  $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
  $mail->isHTML(true);          
  $mail->Subject = 'blabla !';
  $mail->Body = 'Salam,, <br> <b> thanks for your participation grin emoticon you are especial for us grin emoticon  ';
  $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
  if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'no';
    return false;
  } else {
    echo 'sent grin emoticon';
    return true;
  }
}


$email='ayaradwan_93@yahoo.com';
$r=' <a href= "your_page_file_name.php?mail='.$email.'" > Send Email </a> ';

//sendEmail($email); 

if(isset($_GET['mail'])){
  sendEmail($_GET['mail']);
}else{
  echo $r;
}

?>
```

This may be the easiest way for you to implement what you want, still, i strongly suggest the best way to do this is by submitting a form or via AJAX.

Comment: it works (Y) but what if i have other function in this file?

Comment: or if i store this function at other file how can i call it??

Comment: You should have the function defined in the file that executes it. Still, if you have your php functions stored in some other file, you can easily [include it](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp).